Blank Values in Date table for a formula
I am trying to find the week ending for in the date table, however I realise the formula is giving me blanks on some of the months. 
Week Ending on = CALCULATE(MIN([Date]),FILTER('Date',WEEKDAY([Date],2)=6 && [Date]>=EARLIER('Date'[Date])))  

I had used the code below to create a date table
Date = 

ADDCOLUMNS (

CALENDAR (DATE (2024, 07, 1), DATE (2026, 4,31)),

"Year", YEAR([Date]),

"MonthNumber", MONTH([Date]),

"Quarter", QUARTER([Date])

)


you need to get the weeknum first.
pls try this
weeknum = WEEKNUM('Date'[Date])
weekending = CALCULATE(max('Date'[Date]),ALLEXCEPT('Date','Date'[weeknum]))

